# automake: modify implicity make rule to include extra flags

Tags: makefile, autotools, autoconf, automake

How can I add extra flag variables (like CPPFLAGS) that will apply to all makefiles?  Currently, we're using CPPFLAGS, but that is supposed to be reserved as a user variable and I would like to reserve it.  I'd prefer not to use AM_CPPFLAGS because I would like to reserve that for specific Makefile.amS.  What I want is something like GLOBAL_CPPFLAGS that I could set in configure.ac and have it applied to everything.  It would also be nice if there were a way to explicitly ignore the flag.

I think what I need to do is to write my own make rule, but how would I make that available in all subfolders without copying it into every Makefile.am?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct in not using `CPPFLAGS`. That's a [user variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/automake/User-Variables.html#User-Variables). What I'd do is something like this:

In the root of your source dir, create a file called `common.am` and define whatever you need in there:

```
## common.am
AM_CPPFLAGS = -DFOO
```

I know you said you didn't want to use `AM_CPPFLAGS`, but hear me out. In your individual subdirectories, [`include $(top_srcdir)/common.am`](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/automake/Include.html#Include) and extend or override `AM_CPPFLAGS` as needed:

```
## bar/Makefile.am
include $(top_srcdir)/common.am
AM_CPPFLAGS += -DBAR
```

If you want to override, use `=` instead of `+=`:

```
## baz/Makefile.am
include $(top_srcdir)/common.am
AM_CPPFLAGS = -DBAZ
```

Comment: Instead of `include` you could also `AC_SUBST([AM_CPPFLAGS], ["-Whatever"])` from `configure.ac` and then simply update with `+=` in those `Makefile.am` that need it.

Comment: Thanks, I did something similar to this, but opted to use my own variables (e.g. GLOBAL_CPPFLAGS) and AC_SUBST them from from configigure.ac.  Then I included those flags in the equivalent AM_CPPFLAGS in all makefiles and I included AM_CPPFLAGS in target_CPPFLAGS.  I think this gives maximum overall control and what's happening is very explicit.

Comment: @deuberger: If you mean you wrote `target_CPPFLAGS = $(AM_CPPFLAGS)`, you don't have to do that as it's used as the default if not set. If you mean you wrote `target_CPPFLAGS = $(AM_CPPFLAGS) -DFOO`, I can see the point of that.

Comment: yes I meant the latter.  To be specific, anywhere that target_CPPFLAGS was set, I included $(AM_CPPFLAGS) in the definition.  In cases where target_CPPFLAGS was set to nothing, I often just removed it so that AM_CPPFLAGS would be used as you said.

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered your own question: you will have to copy the new rule into every makefile.

Comment: False. automake supports `include`: http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/automake/Include.html#Include

Comment: Jack, that effectively copies the rule, which is what his question was about.

Comment: I suppose it does, but the copying's not done by hand and there's a central place to update the rule or variable.

Answer (score 0):

CPPFLAGS is the mechanism you probably should be using.  Just concatenate the flags you want somewhere in configure.ac:

GLOBAL_CPPFLAGS="-DSOMETHING"

...

CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS $GLOBAL_CPPFLAGS"

and you should be set.

Comment: No, it's not. `CPPFLAGS` is a user variable. http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/automake/User-Variables.html#User-Variables . `AC_SUBST`-ing in common flags isn't a terrible idea, though.